# elasticsearch - score_mode sum don't return expected resutls

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a query with two decay functions ( ES 2.4.4 ), I am using `"score_mode" : "sum"` to sum the decay functions scores + score from the query term. for the test I am using `"boost_mode" : "replace"` to prevent any other scores (from the query) to  affect my score ( I want to test the decay functions ).

these is my decay functions:

`"function_score": {
      "boost_mode" : "replace",
     "score_mode" : "sum",
      "functions": [
        {
          "gauss": {
            "date": {
              "scale": "10d",
              "offset": "15d",
              "decay": 0.9
            }
          }, "weight" : 400
        },
        {
          "gauss": {
            "priority": {
              "origin": "5000",
              "scale": "2000",
              "decay": 0.9
            }
          }, "weight" : 20
        }
      ]`

my results include 2 articles with different dates (2017-08-28 , 2009-05-08) with the same priority (1000) and the same score! (13.122)
how it can be? why doesn't the `2017-08-28` get better score?
so I tried to explain the query.

for 2017-08-28:

```
`"value": 13.122,
              "description": "function score, score mode [sum]",
              "details": [
                {
                  "value": 7.897688e-31,
                  "description": "function score, product of:",
                  "details": [
                    {
                      "value": 1,
                      "description": "match filter: *:*",
                      "details": [

                      ]
                    },
                    { }
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "value": 13.122,
                  "description": "function score, product of:",
                  "details": [
                    {
                      "value": 1,
                      "description": "match filter: *:*",
                      "details": [

                      ]
                    },
                    {
                      "value": 13.122,
                      "description": "product of:",
                      "details": [`
```

I don't understand why the score is 13.122 instead of 13.122 + 7.897. is there a bug with `"score_mode" : "sum"` or is there something I don't understand? the other article from 2009-05-08 has a score of 13.122 for the priority and 0 for the date.

note: I must use `"score_mode" : "sum"` because I want to get top 10 results from each type, and for some of my types date is not relevant so I use an old date whose score is 0, when score mode set to multiply ( elastic default score mode ) all my scores for this type return as 0 because of multiplication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That value isn't 7.897 -- it's 7.897688e-31. So your total score is their sum, which is

```
13.1220000000000000000000000000000007897688
```

i.e., 13.122. :)